# No aparece botón para login con cuenta google en mi pagina web

Tags: c#, .net, aspx

en esta aplicación Utilizo master pages con controles ascx es en donde quiero integrar el botón para el enlace para iniciar sesión por medio de cuenta google en mi pagina web, ya intente varios formas pero no aparece el botón.

El scritp (  ) lo he agregado en el main.master, en el login.ascx y también lo agregue en el login.ascx.cs y aun no funciona.

El botón esta incrustado en el control ascx pero nunca aparece.

La aplicación funciona de la siguiente manera, en la pagina principal existe el menú principal que es en donde podemos elegir y presionar iniciar sesión o crear cuenta, al presionar en iniciar sesión se abre una ventana (esta ventana es el control login.ascx) y aparece una petición de usuario y contraseña, mas abajo un botón de iniciar sesión y debajo de este debería aparecer el botón de iniciar sesión con google pero no aparece

Parte principal del master:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="newsite_Main" Codebehind="Main.master.cs" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9; IE=11" />
    <link href="/Estilo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Estilos_Adver.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/ssMain.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<!--<meta property="fb:fb:admins" content="" />-->
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
 <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

Parte del control ascx:

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="login" Codebehind="login.ascx.cs" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/lblMensajes.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="lblMensajes" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/registrate/registrate.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="registrate" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  }
</script>

                <table style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto; width: 300px; border-spacing: 5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Correo Electrónico:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Contraseña:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" onkeypress="return ontext(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="Aceptar" runat="server" Text="Iniciar Sesión" OnClick="Aceptar_Click" BackColor="#F58821" ForeColor="White" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <%--<asp:Button ID="cancelar" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" OnClick="cancelar_Click" BackColor="#F58821" ForeColor="White" />--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="forget" runat="server" Text="¿Olvidó su contraseña?" OnClick="forget_Click" BackColor="#F58821" ForeColor="White" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="new" runat="server" Text="Crear nueva cuenta" BackColor="#F58821" ForeColor="White" OnClick="new_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" runat="server">"Google"</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Este es el login.ascx.cs:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public delegate void finishlogin(object sender, loginEventArgs e);

    public event finishlogin finished;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PostBackTrigger t = new PostBackTrigger();
        t.ControlID = Aceptar.UniqueID;
        UpdatePanel Panel = (UpdatePanel)Page.Controls[0].FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
        Panel.Triggers.Add(t);

        LiteralControl jsResource = new LiteralControl();
        jsResource.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js\"></script>";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(jsResource);

        const string scriptKey = "UserControlScript";
        string scriptgoogle= "< script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' async defer></ script >";
        string jsP = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";

        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Page.GetType(), scriptKey))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page.GetType(), "g-signin2", Page.ResolveClientUrl(jsP));
        }
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Page.GetType(), scriptKey))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("g-signin2", "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js");
        }
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Page.GetType(), scriptKey))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "g-signin2", Page.ResolveClientUrl(jsP));
        }
                
    }
```

Comment: Si estás sustituyendo en tu código `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` por la key que te da la consola de desarrollador de Google?

Comment: Así es, solo lo cambie al publicarlo aquí, aunque el ID no es necesaria solo para mostrar el botón del enlace